# How to merge local repo cloned from perforce into an existing GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, perforce, git-p4

I have a private repo on GitHub. I have the local workspace of that on my computer.

I have some depo stream in Perforce, that I cloned with "git p4 clone" into a local repo workspace on my computer. The reason is to retain the history from Perforce.

Now I want to push my local repo cloned from Perforce into an existing private repo on GitHub (the one I mentioned at the beginning).

Anyone, can guide me with the steps?

So far I tried:

```
git p4 clone "my-perforce-stream-path"
```

then I tried:

```
git remote add origin "my-private-github-repo-url"
git push -u origin master
```

I get an error:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'my-private-github-repo-url'
```

Comment: before pushing to github, you need to `git pull` from that private repo to your local perfoce repo. Then, when the local repo is sync with the private one, you can go ahead and push from your local to github. Try that out and let me know if it works. Note: if those repos are completely different (not related) you might have another issue

Comment: @CarlosParra, those repos are somehow unrelated. And when I try git pull, I get the following error:

$ git pull
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: yeah, just like I imagine. I left an answer to help you with this problem. Just a quick note, make sure that you really want to do that (have both repositories histories in one repo). If the github one is an new empty repo, I think is ok. but, if that github repo already contains code that's not related to the code in the perforce repo, then you might end up having a bigger problem.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosParra. The reason behind this is that we have all our source code in Perforce and we slowly migrate to GitHub. Some portion was already moved to GitHub. But then a big chunk of restructuring work is done on what was left in Perforce. Now some of the code left needs to be moved. That's what my task was. And in a future after further modifications in Perforce other portions would be moved to GitHub step by step. We couldn't do the whole migration in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to pull from the perforce repo into the private github repository. Once you do that, and the github repo is sync up with the perforce one, you're able to push your master branch to the github repo. Follow one of the two alternatives below to get this done:

**Alternative 1**

1. Create a local copy of the github repo:

   `git clone your-github-repo.git`
2. Add a remote:

   `git remote add p4 "perforce-repo-path"`
3. Pull the changes from the `p4` remote into your local:

   `git pull p4 branch-name`

   3.1. **NOTE**: if both repos, github and perforce are not related (meaning they contains unrelated histories to each other) you might end up having an error because git won't let you merge a branch into another from a unrelated repo. You can override that with the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option, like this:

   `git pull p4 branch-name --allow-unrelated-histories`
4. Finally, you should be able to push your local changes to github:

   `git push -u origin master`

**Alternative 2**

1. Add the github remote in the perforce repo:

   `git add remote github url.git`
2. Next, make sure you pull the history of the github remote branch into your local perforce repo (to sync them up before pushing):

   `git pull github <branch-name> --allow-unrelated-histories` (`--allow-unrelated-histories` helps you prevent receiving an error if both repos contain unrelated changes/histories)
3. Then, push your branch in the perforce repo to the github remote:

   `git push -u github <branch-name>`

   NOTE: If you get any issues about the histories, you can use the same `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag here.

Comment: Step 3 fails:   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
$ git pull p4 "branch-name-of-my-github-repo"
fatal: 'perforce-repo-path' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: check the repo path you're using for the p4 remote. Could you share how it looks that url? Or, try to do it the other way around, create the remote in the perforce repo, and push from there (don't pull). Remember to pass --allow-unrelated-histories when pushing

Comment: The path to my perforce repo is something like //stream/dev/Project1. Even if I try to call "git remote show p4" after the step 2 it complains saying: 

>>>>>>>>>>> 
$ git remote show perforce
fatal: '//stream/dev/Project1' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
<<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: Got it, I see. Problem seems to be with that path and git remote. Can you try the second option as I mentioned? Push directly from perforce repo to github. Add the github remote in perforce repo: `git add remote github url.git`, then `git push github master --allow-unrelated-histories`

Comment: I tried the other option you mentioned and got the error (initially added my remote with my github repo url): >>>>>>>>>> git push -u my-remote-name master --allow-unrelated-histories
error: unknown option 'allow-unrelated-histories' <<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: Run without the 'allow-unrelated-histories' option got error: >>>>>>>>>>>  git push -u my-remote-name master
To my-git-url-path
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'my-git-url-path'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details. <<<<<<<<<

Comment: Look like I managed it to work. Before pushing it into an existing github repo I run "git pull my-remote-name master --allow-unrelated-histories" then I run "git commit -m "my message" then finally "git push -u my-remote-name master". Note, I followed your other option, which is added remote to my github repo for the cloned perforce local repo.

Comment: revise your answer to follow the other option you suggested, that worked for me, so I can mark your answer useful and bump it up. Thanks again for the help :)